# Having an extra attribute (not pivot) in a manytomany relationship with Laravel

Tags: laravel

**TL;DR**

Using Laravel 5.6, I need to add a one-to-many relationship to a many-to-many relation.

I'd like to know if I need another relationship and how to do that if so. Or if I can use the existing pivot table with an extra attribute?

**More details**

[image: many-to-many relationship with pivot]

This screenshot from my pivot table shows how I manage my connections (aka "friends"): when both contacts have accepted the connection, then the *status* equals 1. So far so good, the many-to-many relationship system in Laravel manages perfectly that and everything is working great.

But now, I want to add a "favorite" system to these connections and one user can add another user as a favorite contact, but this is obviously not necessarily a mutual feeling, and the situation could ends up in something like this:

[image: many-to-many relationship with pivot and attribute]

Of course, the many-to-many relationship with two pivots doesn't return anything because the ***starred*** field doesn't have the same value on both records. When I update the second record to "1" as well, the relation is returned correctly.

**Is there a way to use that very table using both a pivot (*status*) and a simple extra attribute (*starred*), or do I need another relationship set up elsewhere? (and how to do it the best way?)**

Comment: you need another pivot table for starring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create starrings table with following data

```
Schema::create('starrings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('starred_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('starred_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

on your User model, add the following:

```
    public function starred(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Starring','starred_id');
    }
    public function starrings(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Starring','user_id');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know

Comment: Using exactly your code, when I try to star a user (with `$this->starred()->save($user)`), the SQL fails and says `Column not found: Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update users set user_id = 1 where id = 2)`. I don't get it because I added `protected $table = 'starrings'` in the model

Comment: to attach user use $user->starred()->attach($another_user)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Well yes, I checked, that's why I was asking :-) According to your code, this is a one-to-many relationship, not a many-to-many. Am I missing something?

Comment: where are you using `$this->starred()->save($user)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168592/discussion-between-pierre-le-bot-and-hussein).